# Laravel Form Input not required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a simple contact form for my users and IF they have an order id to put it in a field. Or else i put it by default as "0" (lets say that they have a question)

So this is my code

```
Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\ContactUS;

class ContactUSController extends Controller
{
    public function contactUS()
    {
        return view('contactUS');
    }

    public function contactUSPost(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        ContactUS::create($request->all());

        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get back shortly.');
    }
}



View

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Contact US Form</h1>

        @if(Session::has('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ Session::get('success') }}
            </div>
        @endif

        {!! Form::open(['route'=>'contactus.store']) !!}

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Name']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Email:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('email', old('email'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Email']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Order ID:') !!}
            {!! Form::number('orderId', old('orderId'), ['class'=>'form-control no-spinners', 'placeholder'=>'Do you have and order id?']) !!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Message:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('message', old('message'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Message']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Contact US!</button>
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}

Model

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContactUS extends Model
{
    public $table = 'contact_us';

    public $fillable = ['name','email','message'];
}

Migration

class CreateContactUsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contact_us', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->integer('orderId')->default('0');
            $table->boolean('solved')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('contact_us');
    }
}
```

So the issue is that when I don't put any value on field `OrderId` it takes the default value `0`
But if i put any number value `1 or 2 etc` it still saves `0` at my database.

Any idea why is this reaction made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow mass assignment for `orderId` field in your model,

```
 public $fillable = ['name','email','message','orderId'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now i have another issue. `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'orderId' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `contact_us` (`name`, `email`, `orderId`, `message`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asd, asd@gormail.com, , asd, 2017-12-28 12:11:03, 2017-12-28 12:11:03))`

Comment: This is because of empty(null) value passed through form

Comment: @SagarGautam ok i understand but i thought this would be ok since i made a default value in `orderId` column ! isn't it?

Comment: Default value will be used when you don't include the column in insert statement but while sending null at accepts

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios When you don't pass key value pair of the column then default value will be consider but if you pass key and null value pair then it will throw this exception. I hope you will understand

Comment: @SagarGautam ok i understand but how can i pass the value '0' if is null ?

Comment: `$data=$request->all();    if($data['orderId']=='') $data['orderId']=0; ContactUS::create($data); `

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios As Deepak said you can check value is null or not while inserting data to database

Comment: ahhh so close. Thanks a lot both of you!

Answer (score 0):

As Deepak stated in the comments, you can check the value for null in your controller:

```php
$data=$request->all();
$data['orderId'] = $data['orderId'] == '' ? 'No Order ID Entered' : $data['orderId'];
```

Alternatively, pass something falsy

```php
$data=$request->all();
$data['orderId'] = $data['orderId'] == '' ? 0 : $data['orderId'];
```